# Updating Product in my database tblProduct

Tags: c#

**I have some saved product in my datase that I want to edit but after editing and hit update the information showned is updated successfully but the new changes does not reflect in the database table. The table has pcode as the primary key**

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to update this Product?", "Update Product", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                string bid = ""; string cid = "";
                //Getting the id of brand
                cn.Close();
                cn.Open();
                cm = new SqlCommand("select id from tblBrand where brand like '" + cboBrands.Text + "'", cn);
                dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                if (dr.HasRows) { bid = dr[0].ToString(); }
                dr.Close();
                cn.Close();
                //getting the id of category
                cn.Open();
                cm = new SqlCommand("select id from tblCategory where category like '" + cboCategory.Text + "'", cn);
                dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                if (dr.HasRows) { cid = dr[0].ToString(); }
                dr.Close();
                cn.Close();
                //Saving Product
                cn.Open();
                cm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblProduct SET barcode=@barcode, pdesc=@pdesc, bid=@bid, cid=@cid, price=@price where pcode like @pcode" ,cn);
               
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", txtPCode.Text);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", txtBarcode.Text);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdesc", txtDescription.Text);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", bid);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", cid);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", txtPrice.Text);
               // cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reorder", txtReorder.Text);
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Product has been successfully updated.", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                clear();
                plist.LoadProducts();
                this.Close();
                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `txtPCode.Text` has a value? And are you sure that that *exact* value exists in `tblProduct`? Show it e.g. in screenshots to convince us, and don't forget to include any leading/trailing spaces in all values. Also, I wonder why you use `LIKE` everywhere, using `=` would make a lot more sense, unless you want to allow the entry of `%12%` and other wildcarded values...

Comment: In sql server, Like operator is used with wildcard %. So if you want to search 'apple' in a column, it should be "Select * from table where name is like '%apple%'. It will return any value than contains apple. For the exact value to return a result ,  you could use equal = operator make sure to use Trim() with text to search for unique names.